# Do you have to release the returned value for ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID?

Tags: iphone

Do you have to release the returned value for ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not have ownership of the return value and thus you do not have to release it.

See [Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH) for details on why this is. Make sure you read and understand the "Create Rule" (further down the page), so you can figure out which objects you have to release if you encounter such a case in the future.